# ros_qt project setup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m using Qt5 in Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS noetic.
Generally the directory structure for ROS Qt project is:

[image: image description]

This can also be seen [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_image_view) in a standard ros_qt project.

But when I create a ROS package in Qt, following directory structure is created:
[image: image description]

Do we have to create other folders and files manually?
What about .ui file, I think it should have been created by the Qt Creator, What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386010/ros_qt-project-setup/) by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2021-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After conducting experiments on the answer provided by @Ranjit Kathiriya , I was able to find that the directory structure for ROS-Qt project and files is not compulsory but it is mandatory to have 4 kind of files:

1. main.cpp
2. mainwindow.cpp
3. mainwindow.h
4. mainwindow.ui
   The names of above files can vary. It is mandatory to declare all files in CMakeLists.txt (they can be located in different folders or same).

In order to run the project the **ui_mainwindow.h** file is mandatory which is auto generated in build directory of catkin workspace if **CMAKE_AUTOUIC** macro is set in CMakeLists.txt.

Also there is no need to manually create 3 of the above mentioned 4 files. Once an empty project is created in Qt Creator go to:
FIle -> New File Or Project
Following window will appear, choose **Qt** under **Files and Classes** and then on right side panel choose **Qt Designer Form Class**, follow steps by clicking on **choose** and you can create files 2, 3 and 4.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) with karma: 47 on 2021-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-10**:
Tick on your answer, that can help someone.

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-09-10**:
:D, currently not credible enough to do that.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-10**:
You can try now.

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-09-10**:
Thank you.